# Displaying article information if approved value is 1 with php fetch_object();

Tags: php, sql, database

i have this code that works below but i want to only display the articles that are approved e.g if the approved value is 1

1.1

```
$result = $con->query("

SELECT articles.id, articles.article_name, AVG(articles_ratings.article_rating) AS rating, articles.approved
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN articles_ratings
ON articles.id = articles_ratings.article_uploaded_id
GROUP BY articles.id ");

    $articles = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

     $articles[] = $row;

      // print_r($articles);

    }
```

1.2

```
$result = $con->query("

SELECT articles.id, articles.article_name, AVG(articles_ratings.article_rating) AS rating, articles.approved
FROM articles WHERE approved = '1'
LEFT JOIN articles_ratings
ON articles.id = articles_ratings.article_uploaded_id
GROUP BY articles.id ");

    $articles = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

     $articles[] = $row;

      // print_r($articles);

    }
```

Getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object()" anyhelp please?.
Thank you

Comment: which MySQL API are you using to connect with here? `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other?

Comment: please echo the error using `mysql_error`

Comment: Basically your query failed and you need to find out why. Check for errors using the associated error checking function, something you're obviously not doing.

Comment: Read up on SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html and the WHERE clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/where-optimizations.html

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala I doubt very much that they're using the `mysql_` API. *But...* stranger things have happened where OP's codes were so messed up and mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yup! That's true. Completely with you.

Comment: Am using mysqli_ to connect. and the echo error i get is --- > Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in c:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE` goes *after* all the joins;

```sql
SELECT articles.id, articles.article_name, AVG(articles_ratings.article_rating) AS rating, articles.approved
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN articles_ratings
  ON articles.id = articles_ratings.article_uploaded_id
WHERE approved = '1'    -- WHERE goes here.
GROUP BY articles.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Joachim it works!! and thank you every one too :).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT articles.id, articles.article_name, AVG(articles_ratings.article_rating) AS rating, articles.approved
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN articles_ratings
ON articles.id = articles_ratings.article_uploaded_id
GROUP BY articles.id , articles.approved
HAVING articles.approved = '1'
```

You can move your condition to a HAVING clause.